# Components positioned off screen causing mobile overflow

Tags: css, vue.js, mobile, safari, tailwind-css

I have a responsive navbar in the form of a hamburger that slides a list of menu options to the left from the right side of the screen on mobile. The initial position of the menu options are on the right of the screen past its width, leading to overflow.

I have added to my tailwind.css file, which is my only css file in my app.

```
body {
  @apply overflow-x-hidden;
}
```

I've tried adding `'initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'` to my meta tags, which 'hides' the problem on desktop mobile-sized browser sizes, by preventing the user from horizontally scrolling to the overflowed area, but on iPhone safari, I still can view and scroll to the overflowed region.

I've tried wrapping my `<ul>` in `<div class="relative overflow-hidden">` but this just stops my list of menu options to slide into view.

````
  <div class="bg-gray-900 text-gray-100 py-3.5 px-6 shadow">
    <!-- Desktop View -->
    <div class="hidden md:flex md:flex-col md:items-center md:justify-center">
      <!-- First Row: Home Button -->
      <HomeButton class="mb-4" />
      <!-- Second Row: Links -->
      <ul class="flex space-x-40">
        <li v-for="(link, index) in Links" :key="index">
          <nuxt-link
            :to="link.link"
            class="text-xl"
            :class="
              hoveredIndices.length > 0
                ? hoveredIndices.includes(index)
                  ? 'text-primary'
                  : 'text-onPrimary'
                : 'text-primary font-mplus1p'
            "
            @mouseover="hoverLink(index)"
            @mouseleave="leaveLink(index)"
          >
            {{ link.name }}
          </nuxt-link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Mobile View -->
    <div class="flex items-center justify-between md:hidden">
      <!-- Spacer for left side to balance the menu icon on the right -->
      <div class="w-10 text-4xl"></div>
      <!-- Home Button -->
      <HomeButton />
      <!-- Menu Toggle Icon -->
      <span class="text-4xl cursor-pointer" @click="MenuOpen()">
        <i :class="[open ? 'bi bi-x' : 'bi bi-list']"></i>
      </span>
      <!-- Dropdown Menu for Links -->
      <ul
        class="absolute z-50 w-full px-10 pb-2 duration-200 ease-linear bg-gray-900"
        style="top: 5.75rem"
        :class="[open ? 'right-0' : 'right-[-100%]']"
      >
        <li v-for="(link, index) in Links" :key="index">
          <nuxt-link :to="link.link" class="text-xl text-white">
            {{ link.name }}
          </nuxt-link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>```
````

Comment: why dont you use css display property for your sliding menu, you will have to apply additional styles for slide animation on that !